# How to trigger focus and blur events when testing an input element in a Reactive form in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I am writing unit test cases using Jasmine. There is a method toggleEvents that will be called on blur and focus events in an input field of Reactive forms as follows.

```
 <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" placeholder="First name" 
     (focus)="toggleEvents('firstName', 'focus')" 
     (blur)="toggleEvents('firstName', 'blur')" />
```

I want to spyOn toggleEvents method, but I am not getting how to trigger the blur and focus events on the element. I am not finding the right syntax as well.

```
it("toggleEvents function should be called when focus event is emitted", () => {
    const spy = spyOn<any>(component, "toggleEvents");
    //component.testForm.controls.firstName ??? How to trigger the event here?
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

My form is declared as

```
this.testForm = new FormGroup({ 
    // Form controls initialization
})
```